# K9Mail doesn't replicate Hotmail / Outlook.com folder structure

Tags: imap, k9-mail, outlook.com

I have switched from the Gmail app to K9Mail yesterday because I needed multi-folder sync. However, I'm having trouble replicating the folder contents from my Hotmail account in K9Mail, a problem I didn't have with Gmail.

The folders not correctly replicated in K9Mail are the "special" folders Drafts, Deleted, Sent, and Junk.

I have found settings to set the special folders in the app, but they always appear to be empty. If I move an e-mail to "Drafts" in K9Mail, it does in fact create a new folder on the server, which happens to have the same name as the Hotmail draft folder.

On the other hand, if I put something in the Hotmail drafts folder, I cannot seem to access it at all in K9Mail.

Is this a shortcoming I have to live with, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using IMAP?

Comment: @Alex.S Yes, I do.